# Can't access file in parent directory using ../

Tags: php

I'm attempting to access the file config.php from the file memfuncs.php.

Here are the locations of the files:

```
html/config.php
html/resources/loginfuncs.php
```

Here is the code I am trying to use:

loginfuncs.php:

```
<?php
    require('../config.php');
    function checklogin($username, $password){
```

However this does not work and produces the error:

```
[Tue Oct 14 15:17:21.304371 2014] [:error] [pid 4431] [client 127.0.0.1:32980] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '../config.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/html/pt90/resources/loginfuncs.php on line 2
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Where is the loginfuncs.php file?

Comment: where is your file "loginfuncs.php"?

Comment: Is "pt90" your public_html directory?  Can you please double check the full paths to your config.php and loginfuncs.php files?  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, the file structure is: **/var/www/html/pt90/resources/loginfuncs.php**  and  **/var/www/html/pt90/config.php**. Apologies, I did not mean to write public_html originally. The html folder is the root folder for localhost

Comment: Where do you **require** your _loginfuncs.php_ file?

Comment: Within login.php, this is located in the root (html) folder.

Answer (score 0):

USe This

```
 require('../../config.php');
```

try this

```
require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../config.php');
```

Comment: Why is it that I need to escape twice?

Comment: for your folder schema

Comment: Looks like you have another subfolder pt90 that you have to pass through. /var/www/html/ **pt90** /resources/loginfuncs.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../config.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

If your loginfuncs file is in `'public_html'` directory...Try `require('config.php');`